# Unable to remotely connect to my IBM WebSphere Application Server

Tags: websphere, websphere-9

I am using the IBM product: Websphere Application Server (WAS), version: Base 9.0.5.2.

I want to connect remotely to my IBM WAS to collect a particular set of data metrics, and to achieve that I followed the steps mentioned [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYMRC_6.0.0/com.ibm.jazz.repository.web.admin.doc/topics/t_server_mon_jsr160rmi.html) I cannot use MBean, as it is not supported by IBM and it is only for testing purposes, so all I am left is with option 2 (in the above link).

In the sample test script attached in the above link, all the files that are mentioned, they are the files present on my IBM WAS. Those files aren't present on my remote machine (from where I am trying to connect to my IBM WAS).
I placed those listed files on my remote machine, and still couldn't connect to my IBM WAS.

How shall I test whether I can connect remotely to my IBM WAS or not?

Can somebody please guide me if I'm missing out on any steps?

Answer (score 0):

Verify if your Websphere JMX port is open on both servers ( in the link 2809 )

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access stats provided by PMI infrastructure, then I would consider using PerfServlet app which is discussed here -  [Retrieving performance data with PerfServlet](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tprf_devprfservlet.html). It gives you access via http, so heavy client and product libraries needed, and returns XML, which you can parse to get stats you need.

Other option would be to write your custom app which would use JMX [Using the JMX interface to develop your own monitoring application](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tprf_pmijmx.html) and make it available for example as REST service.

Or if you just want to monitor values use dedicated monitoring apps, like [IBM Health Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3KLZ/com.ibm.java.diagnostics.healthcenter.doc/topics/introduction.html) or third party tools.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: @HetangModi upvote/accept answer if it was helpful for you ;)

Comment: I am doing that, but stackoverflow has a min requirement of 15 reputation, hence I cannot upvote your answer yet.